# How to match table <td></td> based on <th></th> in Umbraco

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco6

i have some issues trying to match th with the td elements on the table, my code works fine but i shows the data but not in order of the th.
What can i do to make this works as pretend??
Any Help would be apreciated

[image]
My Code

```
<div class="table-responsive ">
                <table class="table table-striped ">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Fundo</th>
                      <th scope="col">IFI</th>
                      <th scope="col">Prospeto</th>
                      <th scope="col">KiiD</th>
                      <th scope="col">Mercado Alvo</th>
                      <th scope="col">Síntese Mensal</th>
                      <th scope="col">Relatório Mensal</th>
                      <th scope="col">Relatório Semestral</th>
                      <th scope="col">Relatório Anual</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                 <tbody>

                     @foreach (var page in selection.Children){

                        if(page.Children.Count() > 0){ 

                        foreach(var subpage in page.Children){

                            var listaPdf = subpage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("listaPdfsFundos");

                               if(listaPdf == null) {
                                    listaPdf = new List<IPublishedContent>();
                                }

                                 <tr>

                                 <td >@subpage.Name</td>

                                 @if(listaPdf != null){

                                    foreach(var row in listaPdf) {

                                    var name = Umbraco.Field(row, "categoriaDoFundo");

                                    var id = Umbraco.Field(row, "documentos").ToString();

                                    var mediaItem = Umbraco.TypedMedia(id);

                                    var url = mediaItem.Url;

                                    <td> <a href="@url" target="_blank"><i class="far fa-file-pdf"></i> </a> </td>

                                    }   
                                }   
                       </tr>    
                    }
                }
             }

              </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all to do with the structure of your data and the way you are trying to lay it out in a table that has a fixed number of columns

Anyway from your picture and your html, it looks like you have 9 columns.

You populate `listaPdf` with

```
var listaPdf = subpage.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("listaPdfsFundos");`
```

A little after that, you write the first column

```
<td >@subpage.Name</td>
```

which is definitely okay. So that is 1 column down and 8 to go.

Now your problems start.  In order for your code to work, you must write out 8 * `<td>` items in order to match your `<th>` headers (1 already written)  + 8).

If `listaPdf` does not contain exactly 8 items then it is not going to work. Your picture above suggests that listPdf contained 3 items so you have written out 4 * `<td>` which do not match up with the 9 * `<th>`

So the first thing to check is whether listaPdf contains 8 items.  If it doesn't you cannot make the above code work without finding some way to link each `mediaItem` to the correct column.

Is there anything in each `mediaItem` that links that item to the correct column?

Comment: @wingyp the solution was to make in the backoffice in umbraco 8 item nulls or not so it will always make 8 <td>

Comment: Glad you sorted it :)